# Using GET and POST to add data to a database in Django

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project that will have a raspberry PI collect data from a set of sensors and then send the data to a django server.

I need the server to then take that data and add it to a database and perform ARIMA time series forecasting on the updated dataset every x seconds after a number of new entries are added.

Can I use POST in the raspberry PI program to **send** the data to that url, and then use GET in a django view to **add** the incoming data into a database?

Comment: Yes, you can post the data from the Pi to your Django app. I don't know what the GET would be doing though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How could I get that data into a database?

Comment: That is what Django does.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **urllib** module or **requests** module in python to send POST request to your Django server.

And you can have Django view to respond to that POST request. Inside this view, you can have method to add the data which sent from your Raspberry Pi program into your database which is at the Django server side.

Therefore you don't need another GET method to deal with adding data into the database in this case.